# Validate value of input with angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation

I have a text input that pulls the value of the `window.location.href`, looks for `?=` and strips out the trailing value which is used as the input value. I can't get the validation to check if there is a value after the `=`, and display an error if there isn't.

The full url it is testing is `http://localhost:3000/admin/tagger.html?=1234567`, where `1234567` should be the value in the textbox. If there is no numeric value after the `=`, show an error.

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.init = function () {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var accountId = url.substr(url.indexOf("=") + 1);
    if ($(".accountNumber").val() !== window.location.href + "?=") {
        alert("ERROR");
    } else {
        $scope.accountNumber = accountId;
    }
}

});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/sLew9ygp/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you questions correctly then you can change your code like this.

```
$scope.init = function () {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var urlParts = url.split('?=');
    var accountId = urlParts[1];

    if (!accountId) {
        alert("ERROR");
    } else {
        $scope.accountNumber = accountId;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but getting the error even when the value is correct: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/sLew9ygp/3/

Comment: This is closer, just need to check that the URL is also not just `http://localhost:3000/admin/tagger.html?`, but how to do it so that I only have to check that it has `?=a-number`, and not everything before it. In other words, how do I ensure that it doesn't validate true if the URL just contains `http://localhost:3000/admin/tagger.html`?

Comment: This update is not allowing me to grab the value of the account number input for use in my JSON form post, if the field is disabled: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/sLew9ygp/6/

Answer (score 0):

If you configure your routing differently, you can for example change the url to: http://localhost:3000/admin/tagger/1234567

Your routing would look something like this:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/admin/tagger/:id', {
         templateUrl: '<path to your html template>'
        }
    });
}]);
```

And then in your function you can use $routeParams to check the value of `:id` like this:

```
myApp.controller('myController', ['$routeParams', function($routeParams) {
     $scope.init = function() {
        if ($(".accountNumber").val() !== $routeParams.id) {
            alert("ERROR");
        } else {
             $scope.accountNumber = accountId;
        }
}])
```

Or something along these lines. The principle is: you can get the number that you want to check by calling $routeParams.id (or $routeParams['id']).

Comment: I tried this, but the structure of the URL is being sent as `?id=some-number`. I tried to reconfigure it, but it isn't working: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/sLew9ygp/2/